# Swisscom S3 Dynamic Storage - signature version with boto3?

Tags: swisscomdev

When creating an S3 client like so:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    endpoint_url=app.config['S3_HOST'],
    aws_access_key_id=app.config['S3_SETTINGS']['accessKey'],
    aws_secret_access_key=app.config['S3_SETTINGS']['sharedSecret'],
    config=Config(signature_version='s3')
)
```

and then trying to upload a file like so:

```
s3.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=_file,
    Bucket=app.config['S3_BUCKET'],
    Key=file_hash,
    ExtraArgs={
        "Metadata": {
            "file_name": file_name
        }
    })
```

it throws `"Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."`

s3v4 does not seem to work either. What signature version should I use?

Comment: what version of Dynamic Storage you are using? Are you on iAPC oder Public? The old dynamic storage uses v2 and the new v4

Comment: iAPC or Public? How would I check which version I am using?